# Dotenv file not being read by server.js

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

Ok guys last question I can't get my process.env file to be read. I tired various different things but it won't be read it's installed in the root directory and I really need this fixed so I can complete this contact form. My emails send fine with the password and username there but I obviously want to avoid that as a solution.
This is at the top and I've installed dotenv.

```
  const env = require('dotenv').config()
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
            host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
            port: 465,
            secure: true,
            service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
                type: "OAUTH2",
                user: "", //set these in your .env file
                pass: "",
                clientId: process.env.OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
                clientSecret: process.env.OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
                refreshToken: process.env.OAUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN,
                accessToken: process.env.OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN,
                expires: 3599
            }
        }));
```

I'm getting an undefined at process.env in my node.js file.

Since it was asked here's my env file

```
GMAIL_USERNAME=asociacioncorazon
GMAIL_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
SMTP_TYPE=OAuth2
OAUTH_CLIENT_ID=849690669826-
OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET=n8rWu8_DjSyI
OAUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN=1//04cnooLauldltCgYIARAAGAQSNwF-L9IryvSURoeKRayYhSLNpKFUU5byLxvWOgDuvMYKRNGe07KYRpck_NU
OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN=ya29.A0AfH6
```

Comment: your `env` file should be named `.env` if you are using default config

Comment: @AmitParameshwar I changed the file name to .env, and I'm getting unresolved variable
user: .env.GMAIL_USERNAME, //set these in your .env file
            pass: .env.GMAIL_PASSWORD,
            clientId: .env.OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,

Comment: How does you .env file look like?

Comment: Posting now and adding to post

Comment: try running it with `-r dotenv/config`. eg. `node -r dotenv/config index.js`

Comment: console.log(require('dotenv').config()) what is the output of this., the.
 problem might be in path of your .env file
my solution `require('dotenv').config({ path: require('find-config')('.env') })`

Comment: Your solution worked @JatinMehrotra I'm forever indebted to you.

Comment: I will post it as an answer, for future reference,accept it as solution so that it may help others :)

Comment: glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

problem is with the execution path.

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: require('find-config')('.env') })
```